# variable is not defined in nodejs... but only at times. I am obviously missing something but what?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a form that works most of the time and did until I added input validation to the code. If I provide valid input, everything works fine. The value gets saved to the DB and there are no errors. However, when I provide invalid input to the form, it returns the following:

```
invalid input
ReferenceError: E:\repos\scantool\scantool\views\scan_targets\new.ejs:4
2|
3| <form action="/scan_targets" method="POST">
>> 4|     <%- include('_form_fields') %>
5|     <a href="/scan_targets">Cancel</a>
6|     <button type="submit">Add</button>
7| </form>

E:\repos\scantool\scantool\views\scan_targets\_form_fields.ejs:2
1| <label>Host name or IP</label>
>> 2| <input type="text" name="host" value ="<%- scantarget.host%>">
3|

scantarget is not defined
at eval (eval at compile 
(E:\repos\scantool\scantool\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:12:17)
at _form_fields (E:\repos\scantool\scantool\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
at include (E:\repos\scantool\scantool\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:690:39)
at eval (eval at compile 
(E:\repos\scantool\scantool\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:12:17)
at new (E:\repos\scantool\scantool\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
at tryHandleCache (E:\repos\scantool\scantool\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] 
(E:\repos\scantool\scantool\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)  
at View.render (E:\repos\scantool\scantool\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
at tryRender 
(E:\repos\scantool\scantool\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
at Function.render 
(E:\repos\scantool\scantool\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
```

Here is the relevant code in routes:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const scantarget = new scanTarget({
        host: req.body.host
}) 
//input validation. valid input has undefined error
const { error, value } = schema.validate({ host_or_ip: scantarget.host });

if ( error === undefined ) {
    try {
        const newscanTarget = await scantarget.save()
        res.redirect('scan_targets')
    } catch {
        res.render('scan_targets/new', {
            scantarget: scantarget,
            errorMessage: 'error adding scan target'
    })
    }
}else{
    res.render('scan_targets/new', {
        errorMessage: 'invalid input type'
    })
    console.log('invalid input')
}


})

module.exports = router
```

Please help. I've been starting at it all day and I think it's just something obvious and stupid that I am missing.

Comment: If `error === undefined` then `scantarget` isn't part of the render data, but w/o knowing what's actually happening, it's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I figured it out.  I changed the else portion of the code:

```
}else{
//todo: fix output of error
    res.render('scan_targets/new', {
        scantarget: scantarget,
        errorMessage: 'invalid input type'
    })
    console.log('invalid input')
}
```

Dave, thanks for the tip. It reminded me to look at how the input was being parsed.